# GridLayout weights on API<23

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm adding automatically generated views (`CheckBoxes`, `RadioButtons` etc.) to `GridLayout` and setting layout params like this:

```
        GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f));
        lp.width = 0;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

But this is working only for API 23+.

API 23+ - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLplp.png

API 21/22 (21 is min) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLDp3.png (just blank space)

I have tried switching from android.widget.GridLayout to android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout (it not solved my problem).

Comment: `GridLayout` is confusing and  unpredictable. Consider using nested `LinearLayout`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use support library `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout` instead of `android.widget.GridLayout`.